# Issue Replacing URL using JS

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to swap out a link on a page using javascript and seem to have hit a wall. I believe the way my URL is encoded might be at fault.

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a[href="https://sis.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=230&subject=BIO&term=202295&_gl=1*1wa2tu7*_ga*MTA4NzY5ODQ3LjE2MjQ4ODM4NjY.*_ga_2575BXQHNN*MTY0OTY5MTI0NC4yNDYuMS4xNjQ5Njk1NDY0LjA"]');
if (a) {
  a.setAttribute('href', 'https://sis.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=130&subject=BIO&term=202295&_gl=1*1wa2tu7*_ga*MTA4NzY5ODQ3LjE2MjQ4ODM4NjY.*_ga_2575BXQHNN*MTY0OTY5MTI0NC4yNDYuMS4xNjQ5Njk1NDY0LjA')
}
```

```html
<a title="View the schedule for BIO230 for Summer 2022" href="https://sis.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=230&amp;subject=BIO&amp;term=202295&amp;_gl=1*3cwusx*_ga*MTA4NzY5ODQ3LjE2MjQ4ODM4NjY.*_ga_2575BXQHNN*MTY0OTY5MTI0NC4yNDYuMS4xNjQ5Njk2MTkzLjA" target="_blank">Summer 2022</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to select this
a[href="https:///sis.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=**230**.....
but in your html you have this
<a title="View the schedule for BIO260 for Summer 2022" href="https:///sis.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=**260**

Basically The code in your condition will never get executed because query selector doesn't find an a tag with that href attribute value.

Comment: I copied the wrong link, there is a while list of these. I updated my code to reflect that error. I'm still having the same issue though.

Comment: Seems like CSS attributes selector doesn't like this "&amp" what I would suggest is using a different approach try to select all the a tags with something like this a[target="_blank"]. Than loop through all of them and compare the href attribute with your link, when they match you have the element you were looking for